# NodeJS / Moongose - mass assign properties from req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model with large number of properties. Is there anyway I can simplify the assignment of `req.body` properties to newly created record?

e.g.

```
var task = new Task();

task.title = req.body.title;
task.desc = req.body.desc;
task.priority = req.body.priority;
// ... 20 more lines here ... //
// task = req.body will not work here

task.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) res.status(500).json({
        msg: err
    });
    res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if task has the same properties as the req.body object you can just:

```
var task = new Task(req.body);
```

(You might also want to sanitize your input , prior to that..)

Hope this helps.